# How to create a finite iterator with contents being a result of an expression?

Tags: scala

I'd like to create an `Iterator` that gets its next element by (repeatedly) evaluating an expression, and I want the expression to be able to return a certain value to terminate it.

The only thing I've found like this is [Iterator.continually()](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator$@continually[A](elem:=%3EA):Iterator[A]), which seems to be infinite. It's important that the expression should not be evaluated until `next()` is called on the `Iterator`.

Is there a way to get this behaviour?

for example:

```
def getNext = {
  // some complicated code
  val next = ... // either a STOP value or a real value to be returned by the iterator
} 

val myIter = Iterator.continually(getNext) // want this to stop at some point
```

Comment: what should the iterator return when it sees the stop value?

Comment: it should not return any more items.

Answer (score 29):

`Iterator.continually` is usually combined with `takeWhile`:

```
var count = 0
def complexCompute(): Int = { count +=1; println("eval " + count); count }

val iter = Iterator.continually { complexCompute() }
iter.takeWhile(_ < 3).foreach(println)
```

Which prints:

```
eval 1
1
eval 2
2
eval 3
```

So if the condition that determines whether the computation should continue can be evaluated outside the computation then this works pretty well.

Basically I guess I'm saying `Iterator.continually(getNext()).takeWhile(_ != certainValue)` will achieve what you're trying to do. It's lazily evaluated.

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked at [scala.collection.immutable.Stream](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html)? It's purpose it to create a sequence like object where the next element is lazily evaluated. It can be finite or infinite.

For example:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.0.final (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_24).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import collection.immutable._
import collection.immutable._

scala> def next(i: Int): Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(i*i, next(i*i))
next: (i: Int)scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int]

scala> val stream = next(2)
stream: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(4, ?)

scala> stream.find(_ > 1000)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(65536)
```

Comment: I think this works really well when recursion is involved. Otherwise I prefer Iterator as there are certain pitfalls with Stream, lots of data and retaining references to the head of th stream.