# IndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: scala, gzip

I'm trying a small program that would read a file, convert that to a array of bytes and zip the bytes and return the zipped bytes back as an array. However, I'm getting IndexOutOfBounds thrown. Here is what I have so far tried!

```
private def getBytePayload(): Array[Byte] = {
  val inputJson: String = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/small_json.txt")).mkString

  val bin: ByteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputJson.getBytes())
  val bos: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

  println("The unCompressed stream size is = " + inputJson.size) // Prints 5330

  val gzip: GZIPOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(bos)

  val buff = new Array[Byte](1024)

  var len = 0
  while((len = bin.read(buff)) != -1) {
    gzip.write(buff, 0, len) // java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown!
  }

  println("The compressed stream size is = " + bos.toByteArray.size)

  bos.toByteArray
}
```

Any pointers as to what has gone wrong?

Comment: see also the `Iterator.continually {...}.takeWhile {...}` pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165152/scala-create-a-finite-iterator-whose-contents-is-the-result-of-an-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as what the problem is, I'm not exactly sure. However, the following code should be revealing. See what it it tells you:

```
val buff = new Array[Byte](1024)

var len = 0
while((len = bin.read(buff)) != -1) {

   //Print out actual contents of buff:

   for(int i = 0; i < buff.length; i++)  {
      System.out.print(i + "=" + buff[i] + ", ");
   }
   System.out.println();

   gzip.write(buff, 0, len) // java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown!
}
```

This is just my style-opinion, but I personally find this confusing

```
while((len = bin.read(buff)) != -1) {
```

and would change it to

```
len = bin.read(buff);
while(len != -1)  {

   //do stuff

   len = bin.read(buff);
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println("buff[" + i + "]: " buff[i]);` I think there is a missing `+` .

Comment: Don't you run into an infinite loop with the one that you changed to?

Comment: I don't see that. I just compacted it to `print` instead of `println`. No logic was changed. Am I missing something?

Comment: I also don't see it with the while-loop style-change, either, if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm confused. Not sure what is happening!

Comment: The while-loop is just a style-change. There is nothing different between my while-loop and your original while-loop. Take it or leave it as you wish. As far as the debugging suggestion I've proposed, give it a try, and see what it tells you.

Comment: I did try printing the bytes. What I noticed is that the buffer was not enough to write all the input bytes. So I increased the buffer size to say 10000 but even that gave me the IndexOutOfBounds

Comment: I realized now what the mistake was. Don't mess with open streams. As soon as you are done using them, close it!